# Limit of domains of derivatives

Tags: derivatives, reference-request

If $f$ is a function with domain $D\subset \mathbb R$, the domain of its derivative $f'$ is a subset of $D$. This leads to the definition of the descending sequence of sets:

$$ D= D_0 \supset D_1 \supset D_2 \supset D_3 \supset \cdots \supset D_n \supset D_{n+1} \supset \cdots$$

where $D_k$ is the domain of $f^{(k)}$. We can then define the limit $D_\infty$ of the sequence $(D_n)_{n\ge 0}$ as

$$ D_\infty = \lim_{n\to\infty} D_n = \bigcap_{n\ge 0} D_n $$

**What does $D_\infty$ look like?**

In particular,

1. Does the sequence stabilize (become constant after some rank)?
2. What are the topological properties of $D_\infty$?
3. Can any subset of $\mathbb R$ be the $D_\infty$ of some function $f$?

I tried some simple example, but I lack imagination.